# How to prevent text to appear cropped on figures?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to use `MATLAB` to design a very simple Stroop task where participants have to decide the color that a word is printed in on the screen. For some reason, the words are always cropped regardless of how big or small the font is.

[image]

I used the following code to set the figure size:

```
h = figure('Position', [1, 1, 1200, 800]);
set(h, 'NumberTitle', 'off', ...
       'Name', 'Stroop Test', ...
       'Color', 'black', ...
       'MenuBar','none', ...
       'ToolBar', 'none');
```

For displaying the actual word stimuli, I used the following code:

```
ht = show_text(h, lang.words(iNoise),...
                'FontSize', 60,...
                'ForegroundColor', lang.colors{iStimul});
```

ADDED:

```
function handle = show_text(parrent, string, varargin)

parpos = get(parrent, 'Position');
pos = [5 round(parpos(4)/2)-30 parpos(3)-10 60];

handle = uicontrol(parrent,...
    'Style','Text',...
    'BackgroundColor', 'black',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'white',...
    'Position', pos,...
    'FontUnits', 'pixels');

if length(varargin) > 0, set(handle, varargin{:}), end;
fontsize = get(handle, 'FontSize');

[outstring,newpos] = textwrap(handle,string);
height = length(outstring) * 1.1 * fontsize;
pos = [5 round(parpos(4)/2)-round(height/2) parpos(3)-10 height];
set(handle,'String',outstring,'Position', pos);
drawnow;

end
```

If someone could tell me what the problem is, that would be great.

Comment: Would you mind showing us what's in the `show_text` function, it's a custom function right?

Comment: oops, forgot to include that! Just added it

Comment: If needed, I can include links to the actual scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you offset the `height` variable in the `show_text` function by a larger arbitrary factor like this:

```
height = length(outstring) * 1.5 * font size;
```

Instead of `1.1`? Or try `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I'd strongly recommend [PsychToolbox](http://www.psychtoolbox.org/) for this...
There are many problems with using the matlab figure for experiments...

The problem you describe is just one of many, and that's why PsychToolbox, cogent etc. were written -- and they do make it easier to code this kind of task.